# How can I Launch Facebook App from my App?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, url-scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [launch facebook app from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app)

I want to open the Facebook app out of my own App using a scheme url. But I dont know how to do that. My scheme url looks like this: fb://page/133105433423897. Maybe via `inent` and/or `parseUri`. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

check out following post describing similar problem:

[URL to open facebook app in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256804/url-to-open-facebook-app-in-android)

copied for quick reference:

You need to use Intents. Here's how to call the FB application (if it is installed):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana","com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");
intent.putExtra("client_id", applicationId);
mAuthActivityCode = activityCode;
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
```