# Is there any possiblility to invoke facebook from android emulator(honey Comb)

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is there any possibility to invoke facebook & twitter app from andriod emulator( im using android emulator 3.2honey comb)

Please help me on this???

Comment: please be specific in ur question, do u have the facebook app installed?

Comment: Ya facebook app is installed in my emulator, bt the thing is i have and image,button on my main screen if i click that image,button it should invoke facebook app installed in my emulator. How can i do that??

Comment: u should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app/4814030#4814030 ... but i feel u will have to use facebook -android sdk..http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/  search on that

Comment: thanks for the help.. so can u please tell me how to invoke twitter app also ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently works, although you can't bet on it when the facebook app updates.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_user_id", user_id);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

You may want to place this in a try-catch(NullPointerException e) block so as not to crash the app when it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hi this is working bt am unable to connect to facebook app with my login credentials.But in browser am able to login with same login credentials..Is there any thing do i need to setup for this..Please help me out???