# Opening facebook app on specified profile page

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I'm trying to use some code from SO but it fails:

Those are uri's supposed to open the right section of the app.

```
facebook://facebook.com/info?user=544410940     (id of the user. "patrick.boos" won't work)
facebook://facebook.com/wall?user=544410940   (will only show the info if you have added it as
```

What I want is to open facebook app on a profile I've specified. This is a code that I'm trying. The number is UID of the profile.

```
        String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/wall?user=417079614970109"; 
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Is it depreciated or what? How do I accomplish such task now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Facebook page from Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Actually it looks like this. These URIs only work with the most recent version of the facebook app. That's why we try catch.

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

    try {
        context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); //Checks if FB is even installed.
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("fb://profile/254175194653125")); //Trys to make intent with FB's URI
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/arkverse")); //catches and opens a url to the desired page
    }
}
```

In your Activity, to open it, call it like so:

```
Intent facebookIntent = getOpenFacebookIntent(this);
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Comment: thank you very much. Much of the threads got depreciated I suppose. There goes my facebook like sentiapps :)

Comment: How do you call this method?  for example  getOpenFacebookIntent (??) - what goes there for the context?

Comment: Just to clarify the number after profile is the users facebook id.  If you only have a username you can get the id from the id field from http://graph.facebook.com/[userName]

Comment: @ZedScio When i try to use "fb://profile/<pageID>" to open a page in facebook app it opens up the page but do not show the like button. Instead a subscribe button is shown. Can you tell me why this issue is happening. My question is at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563908/cannot-see-like-option-in-facebook-page-from-android-device)

Comment: With this approach I can open the desired page in my FB app, thanks for that. But then I face a problem, when I try to "Follow" or "Like" that page, it shows me a toast - "There was a problem following this Profile. Please try again later." I wonder why it could be happening. Any suggestion?

Comment: & here is the answer of that issue, use "page" instead of "profile"- 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15872383/1433187

Comment: you should also add `intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");` it makes the facebook activity open faster!

Comment: As specified in Jareds answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app there is a new adress for the intetnt to open the fb app in version 11+: fb://facewebmodal/f?href=[FACEBOOK_URL] and enter the normal web url there.

Answer (score 13):

This no longer works

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/someProfile"));
```

Please try this instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/someProfile"));
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about to open Facebook Messenger?

Comment: Open Facebook Messenger is not related to this question. Ask a new one

Answer (score 11):

Is this not easier?
For example within an onClickListener?

```
try { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/426253597411506"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/appetizerandroid")));    
}
```

PS. Get your id (the large number) from [http://graph.facebook.com/[userName]](http://graph.facebook.com/%5BuserName%5D)

Comment: the accepted answer will not start an activity so onResume will not be called if it fails

Answer (score 2):

There are so many question about this but this code is worked for me.Facebook changed there policy so for more detail please check this Facebook official **[GRAPH API EXPLORER PAGE](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Clink&version=v2.10)**

```
Intent intent = null;
    try {
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        String url = "https://www.facebook.com/"+idFacebook;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href="+url));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // no Facebook app, revert to browser
        String url = "https://facebook.com/"+idFacebook;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent .setData(Uri.parse(url));
    }
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

For now it is not possible, **Facebook** has been removed this functionality

Comment: Can you link this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this we need the "Facebook page id", you can get it :

- from the page go to "About".
- go to "More Info" section.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### To opening facebook app on specified profile page,

you can do this:

```
 String facebookId = "fb://page/<Facebook Page ID>";
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookId)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For facebook page use like this: http://fb://page/87268309621xxxx
For personal id use like this: http://fb://profile/87268309621xxxx