# Open page in Twitter app from other app - Android

Tags: android, twitter

I was looking for some way to launch Twitter app and open a specified page from my application, without webview.
I found the solution for Facebook here:
[Opening facebook app on specified profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788247/opening-facebook-app-on-specified-profile-page?answertab=active#tab-top)

I need something similar.

[EDIT]

I've just found a solution:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=[user_name]"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/[user_name]"))); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd put more specific exception here: ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: And "twitter://status?user_id=[USER_ID]&status_id=[STATUS_ID]" is possible

Comment: @jbc there is any call back when we click follow ....

Comment: No idea, I can't help you with that @NagarjunaReddy :(

Comment: Prefer to catch a more specific exception, in this case, ActivityNotFoundException. Otherwise you might end up catching other problems (if you add more code to that block).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This worked for me: `twitter://user?user_id=id_num`

Comment: In 2016 just use :
`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/PROFILENAME")));`

Comment: I can have my ID with the link you give us. I use this website : http://mytwitterid.com

Comment: What would this look like if you wanted to use intent? like `https://twitter.com/intent?text=hello`?

Answer (score 49):

Based on fg.radigales answer, this is what I used to launch the app if possible, but fall back to the browser otherwise:

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    // get the Twitter app if possible
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no Twitter app, revert to browser
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/PROFILENAME"));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE**

Added `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` to fix an issue where twitter was opening inside my app instead of as a new activity.

Comment: gives error cannot get users at this time twitter android

Comment: See fg.radigales answer

Comment: that link didn't help me out...anyways I got it from somewhere else and now working :)

Answer (score 10):

Open page on Twitter app from other app using Android in 2 Steps:

1.Just paste the below code (on button click or anywhere you need)

```
Intent intent = null;
try{
   // Get Twitter app
   this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USER_ID"));
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch () {
   // If no Twitter app found, open on browser
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/USERNAME"));
}
```

2.`intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USER_ID"));`

To get USER_ID just write username https://tweeterid.com/ and get Twitter User ID in there

**Reference**: https://solutionspirit.com/open-page-twitter-application-android/

Answer (score 4):

My answer builds on top of the widely-accepted answers from fg.radigales and Harry.
If the user has Twitter installed but disabled (for example by using App Quarantine), this method will not work. The intent for the Twitter app will be selected but it will not be able to process it as it is disabled.

Instead of:

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=2343965036"));
```

You can use the following to decide what to do:

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
if(info.applicationInfo.enabled)
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=2343965036"));
else
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/wrkoutapp"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=[user_name]"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/[user_name]"))); 
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11105103/2) to the question [Open page in Twitter app from other app - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105103/open-page-in-twitter-app-from-other-app-android/74666876) by the OP [jbc25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365440/jbc25) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code snippet. It will help you.

```
//Checking If the app is installed, according to the package name
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) 
        {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

            //In case that the app is installed, lunch it.
            if (packageName != null && packageName.equals("com.twitter.android")) 
            {
                try
                {
                    String formattedTwitterAddress = "twitter://user/" ;
                    Intent browseTwitter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(formattedTwitterAddress));
                                    long twitterId = <Here is the place for the twitter id>
                    browseTwitter.putExtra("user_id", twitterId);
                    startActivity(browseTwitter);

                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                }
            }
        }

        //If it gets here it means that the twitter app is not installed. Therefor, lunch the browser.
        try
        { 
                            String twitterName = <Put the twitter name here>
            String formattedTwitterAddress = "http://twitter.com/" + twitterName;
            Intent browseTwitter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(formattedTwitterAddress)); 
            startActivity(browseTwitter);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
```

Comment: Please, describe how to get "twitter id" more explicitly

Answer (score 1):

For me this did the trick it opens Twitter app if you have it or goes to web browser:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/"+"USERID"));
                    startActivity(intent);
```