# how can i launch a app form other on Android

Tags: android, twitter, launch

How I can launch a Twitter application from another Android application? For example, in my application I have some social buttons when I pushed the button of Twitter now gone to twitter page, but I want to launch the twitter application. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an intent, check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
try {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=" + twitter_user_name)));
}catch (Exception e) {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/" + twitter_user_name)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an implict intent.[you can read about it in general here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html),
and there is a more specific solution for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105103/open-page-in-twitter-app-from-other-app-android)