# Open the Twitter app instead of the site for authorization APP

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I have a site that Login with Twitter API.
User redirect to this link to Accept  :
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX
My problem is that in mobile, it enters the Twitter site through a browser and needs to log in to the Twitter account ** But all users use the Twitter app!!** 
**
Is there a way to enter the Twitter app through the site and confirm without the need to log in again?
**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to open Twitter App.

```
twitter://endpoint?token=X
```

More information in this StackOverFlow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105103/open-page-in-twitter-app-from-other-app-android).

Comment: this work just  for https://twitter.com, you can use this url for test:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=h2BP1wAAAAABRkP3AAABgAW4kAM

Comment: Don't Work for api