# Cannot see like option in facebook page from android device

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I am trying to open a facebook page from my app in both android and ios. In ios the page shows **LIKE** button but in android it shows **SUBSCRIBE** button instead. Can anyone tell me how to change this to like button in android. I have given the screenshots below. [image: android screenshot]

[image: ios screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved this issue by using the URL `fb://page/pageID` instead of `fb://profile/pageID`