# open Facebook with Intent and url facebook

Tags: android, facebook, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

when I load a url with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(intent);
```

when it starts with "https://twitter.com", it offering me different android applications including Twitter. But when I load a url when she starts with "https://facebook.com" android proposed that browsers do.

I know that I can pry open with the facebook app if I use the API, but I just have one button in my application for facebook and I do not think the API is the lightest. Do you have any idea to overcome this requirement and ensure that android offers me even when facebook?

Those who think what this post is already answered are right, but the facebook API is heavy and I'd try to avoid. thank you for your understanding. I hope that there is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fb://root` as the url in the above code.

Comment: I find the solution on the other hand, by intercepting the link to my page and testing for the presence of facebook app. By cons, the user has no choice, facebook app if it is installed or the choice between browsers.

thank you for your help