# Android Intent to launch Google+ app at Google+ Community screen

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

There is already a good SO question for displaying a Google+ Page in the Google+ Android app:

[Open Google Plus Page Via Intent In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867989/open-google-plus-page-via-intent-in-android)

But what about the Intent to launch the Google+ app at a specific Google+ Community?

EDIT - to the silent down-voters, please explain why you down-voted.

Comment: Did you find a real solution? Not sure if the accepted answer ever worked, but it doesn't anymore. It was bad anyway...

Comment: @JacekKwiecień I've since accepted another answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution, working with G+ version "5.3.0.91034052", tested today

```
final Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "https://plus.google.com/communities/107847486351510098159" ) );
intent.setPackage( "com.google.android.apps.plus" );
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) { 
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

It's not bullet proof, you need Google+ app on your device, in case you don't have it some kind of try-catch might be nice (?),

Comment: Instead try-catch you can resolve intent ```if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}```

Comment: You can remove the "/u/0" part from the Uri

Comment: Thanks for both comments, for future readers (with similar problem) don't use "setClassName" in your intents, in case of G+ application that was the issue, Google devs changed class namespace and class name. Instead stick to "setPackage" which indicates applicationId and you cannot change this one on Google Play once app is uploaded there.

Comment: Better still: `if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) { 
 intent.setPackage(null);
 if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) { 
  intent = null;
 }
}
if (intent != null) {
    startActivity( intent );
}`

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this by using:

```
String communityPage = "communities/123456789";
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
                "com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.UrlGatewayActivity");
        intent.putExtra("customAppUri", communityPage);
        startActivity(intent);
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // fallback if G+ app is not installed
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/"+communityPage)));
        }
```

Where 123456789 is the id of the community copied from the address bar.

Comment: Looks like this activity is not declared in the new Google+ app. This code used to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else needs to do this I had to do this in my app and used the below code

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/communities/1234356789")));
```

Where 1234356789 is the community id from the address bar.

This then prompts whether you want to open with Google+ or browser.