# Open Facebook Place's Page from Android App

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I'm Trying to open my app page on facebook so users can like it

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app) solution, but can't seem to find a way to access pages through facebook's scheme mechanism, using the solution code, with my page id open my page in facebook's android app, but like button is missing, and subscribing page fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer:

```
    public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

       try {
        //context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/576525422362966"));
       } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/576525422362966"));
       }
    }
```