# Do I need to create a Facebook app to reach only one page on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to put a button which directs user to someone's personal profile page or a fan page in Android.

I may basically put the fan page's link to the button. However what I want is that the page should be open on the Facebook app which user already has on his phone.

In other words when I touch the button Facebook app will open and show the specific page, not the browser.

So, do I need to create a Facebook app to implement this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Facebook app responds to the fb:// protocol, so you can create a button that opens a page like this:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    try{
        getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/[id]"));
    startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://facebook.com/[yourpage]"));
        startActivity(intent);      
    }

}
```

This code will check if the Facebook app is installed (credits to [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)) and if so, open the page there. Otherwise, it will open it in the browser.

Now, to actually get the page id, you will need to go to graph.facebook.com/[yourpageurl]. Your "page URL" is the last part of your Facebook URL (ie. http://facebook.com/thisparthere) when you are on the page. Once you find it and visit the graph page, copy the "id" field and that is what you need to put in your fb:// URL.

I tested this on Android 4.3 with the latest FB app, so my apologies if it doesn't work on other versions...