# Open Facebook Url with Facebook application

Tags: android, intentfilter

I  want to open an Facebook link from my android application.
The URL is looks like http://www.facebbok.com/abcxyz. It should open the 'abcxyz' page in the Facebook application, but it is always opening in browser.

**Code:**

```
try 
{
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    activityContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

My android OS version is 6.0.1.

I have the same issue with Instagram, http://www.instagram.com/abcxyz, while other applications like Youtube work.

Comment: Does this work.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526882/open-facebook-page-from-android-app-in-facebook-version-v11 ..?

Comment: @DemoUser the below solution worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use facebook's custom url scheme to force app to open your page like below:

```
public Intent getFacebookIntent(String url) {

  PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

  try {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
    if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
      uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + url);
    }
  }  

  catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
  }

  return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
}
```