# Open Facebook Profile in Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Note**: This issue only arises *when the Facebook app is installed*.

I'm trying to open a user's Facebook profile page when an `ImageButton` is clicked. After looking at [this suggested method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/1986871) for more recent Facebook app versions, it's mostly working, with the exception of users that are *friends* with the logged in user (in the app), or the logged in user themselves.

The process is:

1. Image button is clicked
2. Call to Facebook Graph API is made to get the link to the user's profile via their Facebook ID (stored in our database)
3. A new `Intent` is created by checking to see if the Facebook app is installed, and generating the correct Uri
4. A new `Activity` is started with the generated `Intent`

Because we're using Facebook Graph API v2.0, the `username` field is removed from the `GraphUser` object in the JSON. The problem is that the Facebook link (`GraphUser.getLink()`) is either:

1. An app-scoped (protected) link if the user (logged into the app) is **not** friends with the user whose profile we are trying to view; format is : `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{protected-id}`
2. A 'normal' Facebook link with the user's real id (unprotected); format is: `http://www.facebook.com/{real-user-id}`

The real problem is that the Facebook Uri *when the app is installed* expects either:

1. An app-scoped link
2. A link with the **`username`** attached to it, ***not* `{user-id}`**

However, the *web version* (opened in a web view) doesn't care. The link can be app-scoped, username-based or id-based. So everything **works** for `WebView`s.

Since `username` is completely inaccessible in Graph API v2.0, I'm just getting `null` values, which means that for the **Facebook app** I can't generate the correct Uri that it expects (username-based), only id-based or app-scoped.

Here is the code that I'm using to create the `Intent`:

```
public static Intent getFacebookIntent(String facebookProfileUrl) {
    PackageManager pm = App.getContext().getPackageManager();
    Uri uri;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + facebookProfileUrl);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        uri = Uri.parse(facebookProfileUrl);
    }
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
}
```

And here is my `onClick()` method on the `ImageButton`:

```
new Request(
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        String.valueOf(mate.getFacebookId()),
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                GraphUser g = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphUser.class);

                String fbUrl = g.getLink();
                // TODO: If link does not contain 'scoped', need USERNAME, not ID

                String otherUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/" + myAppUser.getId();

                String finalUrl = (fbUrl.contains("scoped")) ? fbUrl : otherUrl;

                Intent intent = getFacebookIntent(finalUrl);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
```

I need the `username` if the app is installed, otherwise the web view deals with it as it should.

So the question: *How can I get a Facebook username by id for the Facebook app*? Or, **is there a different Uri** that the Facebook app expects that I can account for, using *ids* and *not usernames*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the fb://profile/{user-id} URL format to launch native apps. This will let you use the user ID instead of a username. You could rewrite your getFacebookIntent method as:

```
public Intent getFacebookIntent(GraphUser user) {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Uri uri;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        uri = Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + user.getId());
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        uri = Uri.parse(user.getLink());
    }
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
}
```

You could then call this method and pass in the GraphUser object.

Comment: Oddly enough I ended up trying this before you had posted your answer. I forgot about this question after that, but I'm back now to make sure I gave you a +1 and accepted. Thanks!