# Open Facebook Event in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

In Android, there is a way to open Facebook application in a specific event page?

There is a intent to do this?

Comment: check out this. you just have to replace the links with you facebook event link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app

Comment: @Carmine This is exactly what i wanted. I just start a activity with a action view intent direct to fb://event/<event-id> and the app opens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is installed just create an action view intent direct to "fb://event/" and the app will open.

If it isn't, this will throw an exception.

Alternative: use the direct url of the facebook event, and the browser will open.