# Open facebook page in App not the browser

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-like

I have a link to my facebook, on my website, which opens in the phone's browser.

I would like it to open in the facebook app by default, if the app is installed.

Is this possible?

Comment: The link is on my website and currently a standard <a> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it may not be possible, check this thread:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37549/force-link-to-open-in-app-not-my-default-browser

But if you really want to do it, you can follow the same principle as it is proposed on this URL:
[Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

In short, try to build an URL of form: `fb://profile/pageID`. The point of building such URL is because of `IntentFilter` defined in Facebook app. I am not sure if it will work, but if there is no Facebook app installed this will probably fail.

That should work when you click on a link in browser. It may depend on a browser though.

Comment: sweet I can detect the device with JS and swap out the src.

Comment: the only problem is that you cannot really detect if a user has installed facebook or not