# Impossible to open an Facebook page in the App since <a href=''> in html

Tags: html, facebook

After looking for many solutions everywhere without result, I turn to you! 
I tested many way to open an Facebook Page into the app since  but nothing works, I leave you what I tested (it does not work exept the profiles)

Pages :

```
<a target="_blank" href="fb://facewebmodal/f?href=mypage"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="fb://page/mypage"></a>
```

But profiles work :

```
<a target="_blank" href="fb://profile?id=id"></a>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810803/4398840).

Answer (score 0):

well it opens the new tabs in my browser. It means your links are incorrect. If you are refering to a mobile app then you need to make the pages as a new html page linked to the  element of the parent page and remove the target attribute