# How to open smart Links in-app (bit.ly , on.fb.me)

Tags: android

I want to open a page in fb app using a deep link (on.fb.me/xxx) but it opens in the web browser, is there a way I can do this? or Am I forced to use the usual fb url (fb://xxx).

the code I'm using right now

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://on.fb.me/xxx");

    final Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    facebookIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    try {
        startActivity(facebookIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
    }
```

**I have the same issue with Instagram and Twitter with links like "bit.ly/xxx"**

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app

Comment: yep, but this only works with normal links or page name, but I want to use a smartlink in order to track redirictions.