# issue while opening user facebook page by user_link

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZogY.jpg) error message while trying to open the facebook page of the user.The strange thing is that if I have a mutual friend with that user the page loads with no problem, but I don't think it's default behavior, otherwise I can't understand the meaning of `user_link` permission.

Facebook has approved `user_link` permission and I passed App Review.

From developer account I changed the API version the app calls to `v3.1`.

The way I am getting `user_link`

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("user_gender", "user_link"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                       makeGraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                    }
                });


 public void makeGraphRequest(AccessToken token) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                token, (object, response) -> {
                    try {
                        userStorage.setUserProfileUrl(object.getString(AppConstants.LINK));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name,gender,link,picture.width(700).height(700)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

And using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app) answer for opening the page.

```
  Intent intent;
                try {
                    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + currentUser.getLink()));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    intent = new Intent(context, FacebookWebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.USER_LINK, currentUser.getLink());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
```

I will be very thankful if someone can suggest any solution. I faced this issue before the facebook new API version also.

Comment: @ Levon Petroysen , i have valid use case  for user _ link but apart from my profile i can not open the profile of other as my app review is pending. I have created test app so that i can use user_link permission and i am receiving user_link properly but i want to show profile to other friend in my app but when i try to open my friends url which link return its giving link broken error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/?hc_location=ufi) post we can find the following bit of text

> For most apps, links will only redirect to the individual's Facebook
>   profile for logged in people in the person's extended network.

So, I guess there is no way to be 100% sure that the user page will be loaded properly.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue now. What is "Extended network"? What does it mean no way to be 100% sure? It's programming, stuff needs to be 100% accurate, what kind of API is that then :)
Moreover, when users cannot access they just get a PAGE NOT FOUND, not some explanation or anything. This makes our website look buggy..

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#login

> ...the following fields that belonged to public_profile are deprecated...

As you can read in the changelog, the "link" and "gender" fields are deprecated.

Edit: But they have introduced new permissions `user_link` and `user_gender` so that users can explicitly asked for those particular fields. (Thanks to CBroe for pointing that out)

Comment: That is a bit of unlucky phrasing in the changelog, I think - they are “deprecated” as being part of what `public_profile` gives you access to. But they have introduced new permissions [`user_link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-user_link) and `user_gender` so that users can explicitly asked for those particular fields.

Comment: did you try with the latest api version? btw, in the api reference, it still says "link", so maybe just the permission is called "user_link", and the field is still the same? earlier, there was no separate permission for it.