# How to search for hashtags in facebook application through intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get a result of hashtag search in facebook application through intent.
I just want to pass hashtag keyword in facebook application and search inside facebook application and user can interact with facebook.

I've tried to use fb://hashtag/%s but it is not working
here is my code:

```
 var uri:Uri? = null
        try {
            val applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0)
            if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/1048340
                uri = Uri.parse("fb://hashtag/%$search")
            }
        } catch (ignored: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        }
        return Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
```

In Mobile result should be like this:

[image: Facebook Hash tag]

Comment: any update on this please ?