# Open complete facebook page from android app in facebook app

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, kotlin

I want to open a Facebook page in Facebook app from my android app. The page is opening but does not look like complete Facebook page like it normally looks. It is not showing the profile image and cover image.

I am using the following code to open the page.

```
        var uri = Uri.parse(url)
        try {
            val applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0)
            if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/1048340
                uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=$url")
            }
        } catch (ignored: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        }

        return Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
    }
```