# Open a Facebook post URL in android Facebook app programmatically

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, mobile

I'm coding an android - java app which can open a Facebook post url 
(ex: https://www.facebook.com/BaHangXom.0/videos/2377836809193490).
I tried some ways to start Facebook app with intent but unsuccessfully.

```
    Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + "https://www.facebook.com/BaHangXom.0/videos/2377836809193490"));
    intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Could you please give me any idea?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

Comment: I tried it, however It seems not work on new facebook app :(

Answer (score 1):

Simply open the url:

```java
Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/BaHangXom.0/videos/2377836809193490"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the most simple and universal way: user will be able to choose (and remember the choice) whether they want to open the link via main Facebook app, Facebook lite, or the browser.

Comment: Is there any ways to open directly facebook app without user’s choose?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the facebook app using this code:

```
public static Intent newFacebookIntent(PackageManager pm, String url) {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
  try {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
    if (applicationInfo.enabled) {
      // http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/1048340
      uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + url);
    }
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
  }
  return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
}
```