# Trouble Loading is shown when open FB page from Android application

Tags: java, android, facebook

I can open FaceBook page in browser:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/<page_name>")));
```

I can open my profile page in FB application:

```
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=http://www.facebook.com/<face_book_name>")));
```

But when I try to open the Facebook page (not personal, but page) in FB application:

```
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=http://www.facebook.com/<page_name>")));
```

I get "Trouble Loading":
[image]
So, how can I open a Facebook page in Facebook app from my application on Android?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not solve the issue, as I can open "person" page, but have a problem to open "company" page.

Comment: Maybe the company link is broken or the page is locked. Have you tried opening the page in another mobile?

Comment: The page is opened in browser correctly

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=http://www.facebook.com/<page_name>". In this link what is< page name>?

Comment: The full link is:
https://www.facebook.com/suspilne.news/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: use **page ID** instead of **page name**. For example, the needed page is https://www.facebook.com/suspilne.news, so I should use https://www.facebook.com/148182332275963 instead.

I've found this id when open the page in browser on Android.

Comment: Oh good. But now IDs are not much used. It is your choice. :D