# Is there any new way to open fb url directly in fb not browser?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

```
 public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context,String url) {

        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        }
    }
```

I used this code and it was working but now it does not.
I need any intent to open a url in Facebook directly.
This post helped me, [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Open facebook url

```
    private void openFacebookApp() {
    String facebookUrl = "www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXX";
    String facebookID = "XXXXXXXXX";

    try {
        int versionCode = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;

        if(!facebookID.isEmpty()) {
            // open the Facebook app using facebookID 
(fb://profile/facebookID or fb://page/facebookID)
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://page/" + facebookID);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        } else if (versionCode >= 3002850 && !facebookUrl.isEmpty()) {
            // open Facebook app using facebook url
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + facebookUrl);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        } else {
            // Facebook is not installed. Open the browser
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(facebookUrl);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Facebook is not installed. Open the browser
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(facebookUrl);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
    }
}
```

#### Add query in manifest

```
    <queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.gm" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but if the link is provided as www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx the app open in a different way but at least the Facebook app opens automatically.